# Как корректно комбинировать OAuth авторизацию с обычной авторизацией в Spring Boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth2

Использую следующую конфигурацию для реализации авторизации через oauth & обычная авторизация.

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                    .authorizeRequests().mvcMatchers("/robots.txt").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers(
                            "/", "/auth", "/signup", "/restore", "/activation/**",
                            "/admin/login", "/admin_restore",
                            "/agreement", "/privacy", "/about-us", "/faq", "/contact-us",
                            "/error",
                            "/page/**", "/categories", "/categories/**"
                    ).permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()

                    .and()
                        .formLogin()
                        .loginPage("/auth")
                        .loginProcessingUrl("/auth")
                        .usernameParameter("email")
                        .passwordParameter("password")
                        .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
                        .failureUrl("/auth?authError")
                        .permitAll()

                    .and()
                        .rememberMe()
                        .rememberMeParameter("remember-me")
                        .tokenValiditySeconds(86400)

                    .and()
                        .logout()
                        .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                        .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
                        .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")

                    .and()
                        .oauth2Login().defaultSuccessUrl("/oauth")

                    .and()
                        .exceptionHandling()
                        .accessDeniedPage("/403")

                    .and()
                        .csrf()

                    .and()
                        .sessionManagement()
                        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.ALWAYS)

                    .and()
                        .headers().frameOptions().sameOrigin();
        }
```

В принципе, авторизация работает корректно. НО! Мне также необходимо при авторизации пользователя зафиксировать дату и время его авторизации.
Рабочий функционал для обычной авторизации уже реализовал, а вот с авторизацией OAuth2 наблюдаются проблемы.

```
@Service
public class UserService implements
        ApplicationListener<AuthenticationSuccessEvent> {

/** 
Переопределяем метод onApplicationEvent(), чтобы при авторизации юзера зафиксировать дату и время его авторизации
   */
  @Override
  public void onApplicationEvent(AuthenticationSuccessEvent event) {
    >>> Ex.here!  String userEmail = ((UserDetails) event.getAuthentication().
            getPrincipal()).getUsername();
    User user = this.userRepository.findByUserEmail(userEmail);
    user.setLastAuthDate(LocalDateTime.now());
    userRepository.save(user);
  }
...
}
```

Если авторизоваться через oauth, то выпадает следующее исключение:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.oidc.user.DefaultOidcUser cannot be cast to org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails
```

Соответственно, вопрос - как устранить это исключение, чтобы авторизация при входе на сайт фиксировалась и для oauth пользователя?
Как вообще можно отличить обычного пользователя от авторизованного по oauth? А то с этим у меня проблема наблюдается...

Заранее благодарю Вас за помощь!

Comment: Почему бы не проверять какой тип у `event.getAuthentication().getPrincipal()` и не кастовать к этому типу, беря из него email подходящим методом?

Comment: Благодарю! Сейчас попробую)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, благодаря подсказке по поводу проверки типа авторизации решил вопрос. Не знаю насколько хорошо получилось реализовать задачу, но код рабочий.

```
 @Override
  public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationEvent appEvent) {

    if (appEvent instanceof AuthenticationSuccessEvent)
    {
      AuthenticationSuccessEvent event = (AuthenticationSuccessEvent) appEvent;

      if (event.getAuthentication() instanceof UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken) {
        String userEmail = ((UserDetails) event.getAuthentication().
                getPrincipal()).getUsername();
        User user = this.userRepository.findByUserEmail(userEmail);
        user.setLastAuthDate(LocalDateTime.now());
        userRepository.save(user);

      } else if (event.getAuthentication() instanceof OAuth2LoginAuthenticationToken) {

        Authentication authentication = event.getAuthentication();

        OAuth2LoginAuthenticationToken oAuth2LoginAuthenticationToken = (OAuth2LoginAuthenticationToken) authentication;

        OAuth2AuthorizedClient client = authorizedClientService
                .loadAuthorizedClient(
                        oAuth2LoginAuthenticationToken.getClientRegistration().getRegistrationId(),
                        oAuth2LoginAuthenticationToken.getName());

        String userInfoEndpointUri = oAuth2LoginAuthenticationToken.getClientRegistration()
                .getProviderDetails().getUserInfoEndpoint().getUri();

        String userFullname = "";
        String userEmail = "";

        if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(userInfoEndpointUri)) {
          RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
          HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
          headers.add(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Bearer " + oAuth2LoginAuthenticationToken.getAccessToken()
                  .getTokenValue());
          HttpEntity entity = new HttpEntity("", headers);
          ResponseEntity<Map> response = restTemplate
                  .exchange(userInfoEndpointUri, HttpMethod.GET, entity, Map.class);
          Map userAttributes = response.getBody();

          userFullname = userAttributes.get("name").toString();
          userEmail = userAttributes.get("email").toString();

        }

        User userFromDbEmail = this.userRepository.findByUserEmail(userEmail);

        // Добавить нового пользователя авторизованого через oAuth
        if(userFromDbEmail == null) {

          User user = new User();
          user.setUserEmail(userEmail);
          user.setUserFullname(userFullname);
          user.setUserActive(true);
          user.setRegDate(LocalDateTime.now());
          user.setLastAuthDate(LocalDateTime.now());
          user.setUserRating(0);
          user.setReceiveMessageEmails(true);
          user.setReceiveNotificationEmails(true);
          user.getRoles().add(Role.USER);
          userRepository.save(user);

        } else {

          userFromDbEmail.setLastAuthDate(LocalDateTime.now());
          userRepository.save(userFromDbEmail);
        }

      }

    }

  }
```

Ловим AuthenticationSuccessEvent и смотрим на его тип.
Обычная авторизация - UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
OAuth2 авторизация - OAuth2LoginAuthenticationToken

Далее если обычная авторизация, то находим пользователя в БД и фиксируем текущее время авторизации.
Если oauth2 авторизация и если в БД нет этого пользователя, то создаем его, а если этот юзер есть, то находим его и фиксируем время последней авторизации.